# What is a consume operation in the C++11 Standard?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, semantics, memory-model

I have seen that [this question on acquire, release, consume, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526419/does-the-c11-standard-formally-define-acquire-release-and-consume-operations) exists, however, no answer really defines what a "consume operation" actually is.

In 1.10 paragraph 5 it states:

> A synchronization operation on one or more memory locations is either a consume operation, an acquire operation, a release operation, or both an acquire and release operation.

I wondered if someone can explain what this is as it is used in section 1.10 of the C++11 standard?

Comment: I think it's explained well in "C++ Concurrency in Action" by Anthony Williams (but I forgot).

Comment: @KerrekSB I think it may be time for me to acquire that book.

Comment: @TonyTheLion: Yes, that book explains it quite well

Comment: My guess at the moment is that it has to do with data dependencies, e.g. loading a pointer concurrently and dereferencing that... Also note [`std::kill_dependency`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7150395/what-does-stdkill-dependency-do-and-why-would-i-want-to-use-it).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently, after some searching around, a "consume operation" is a memory operation where a value read from memory is used after the load in several operations, and creates a data dependency.

Being able to order operations without introducing explicit memory fences, is what the apparent (from my understanding) goal is of `memory_order_consume`.

> With `memory_order_consume`, the compiler and CPU are *required* to order the load in question against only those subsequent loads and stores whose address or value are computed from the value loaded. 
>   [source](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1525.htm)

Later in this text it says:

```
/*Example code elided */
```

> The key point is that the `atomic_load_explicit()` using `memory_order_consume` guarantees that subsequent accesses will see any initialization carried out by `insert_foo()`, even if they are executing concurrently, and without the overhead of explicit memory-fence instructions. In constrast, `memory_order_acquire` would require explicit memory barriers on weakly ordered systems and would overconstrain compiler optimizations on all systems.

C++11 Standard draft n3485 defines `memory_order_consume` as:

**29.3 Order and consistency [atomics.order]**

> memory_order_consume: a load operation performs a consume operation on the affected memory location.

So from my understanding it is to order memory loads so that subsequent loads and stores using that load are indeed *subsequent*.  In other words, the load is being *consumed*.