# Do current x86 architectures support non-temporal loads (from "normal" memory)?

Tags: c++, caching, x86, cpu-cache, prefetch

I am aware of multiple questions on this topic, however, I haven't seen any clear answers nor any benchmark measurements. I thus created a simple program that works with two arrays of integers. The first array `a` is very large (64 MB) and the second array `b` is small to fit into L1 cache. The program iterates over `a` and adds its elements to corresponding elements of `b` in a modular sense (when the end of `b` is reached, the program starts from its beginning again). The measured numbers of L1 cache misses for different sizes of `b` is as follows:

[image]

The measurements were made on a Xeon E5 2680v3 Haswell type CPU with 32 kiB L1 data cache. Therefore, in all the cases, `b` fitted into L1 cache. However, the number of misses grew considerably by around 16 kiB of `b` memory footprint. This might be expected since the loads of both `a` and `b` causes invalidation of cache lines from the beginning of `b` at this point.

There is absolutely no reason to keep elements of `a` in cache, they are used only once. I therefore run a program variant with non-temporal loads of `a` data, but the number of misses did not change. I also run a variant with non-temporal prefetching of `a` data, but still with the very same results.

My benchmark code is as follows (variant w/o non-temporal prefetching shown):

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   uint64_t* a;
   const uint64_t a_bytes = 64 * 1024 * 1024;
   const uint64_t a_count = a_bytes / sizeof(uint64_t);
   posix_memalign((void**)(&a), 64, a_bytes);

   uint64_t* b;
   const uint64_t b_bytes = atol(argv[1]) * 1024;
   const uint64_t b_count = b_bytes / sizeof(uint64_t);
   posix_memalign((void**)(&b), 64, b_bytes);

   __m256i ones = _mm256_set1_epi64x(1UL);
   for (long i = 0; i < a_count; i += 4)
       _mm256_stream_si256((__m256i*)(a + i), ones);

   // load b into L1 cache
   for (long i = 0; i < b_count; i++)
       b[i] = 0;

   int papi_events[1] = { PAPI_L1_DCM };
   long long papi_values[1];
   PAPI_start_counters(papi_events, 1);

   uint64_t* a_ptr = a;
   const uint64_t* a_ptr_end = a + a_count;
   uint64_t* b_ptr = b;
   const uint64_t* b_ptr_end = b + b_count;

   while (a_ptr < a_ptr_end) {
#ifndef NTLOAD
      __m256i aa = _mm256_load_si256((__m256i*)a_ptr);
#else
      __m256i aa = _mm256_stream_load_si256((__m256i*)a_ptr);
#endif
      __m256i bb = _mm256_load_si256((__m256i*)b_ptr);
      bb = _mm256_add_epi64(aa, bb);
      _mm256_store_si256((__m256i*)b_ptr, bb);

      a_ptr += 4;
      b_ptr += 4;
      if (b_ptr >= b_ptr_end)
         b_ptr = b;
   }

   PAPI_stop_counters(papi_values, 1);
   std::cout << "L1 cache misses: " << papi_values[0] << std::endl;

   free(a);
   free(b);
}
```

What I wonder is whether CPU vendors support or are going to support non-temporal loads / prefetching or any other way how to label some data as not-being-hold in cache (e.g., to tag them as LRU). There are situations, e.g., in HPC, where similar scenarios are common in practice. For example, in sparse iterative linear solvers / eigensolvers, matrix data are usually very large (larger than cache capacities), but vectors are sometimes small enough to fit into L3 or even L2 cache. Then, we would like to keep them there at all costs. Unfortunately, loading of matrix data can cause invalidation of especially x-vector cache lines, even though in each solver iteration, matrix elements are used only once and there is no reason to keep them in cache after they have been processed.

**UPDATE**

I just did a similar experiment on an Intel Xeon Phi KNC, while measuring  runtime instead of L1 misses (I haven't find a way how to measure them reliably; PAPI and VTune gave weird metrics.) The results are here:

[image]

The orange curve represents ordinary loads and it has the expected shape. The blue curve represents loads with so-call eviction hint (EH) set in the instruction prefix and the gray curve represents a case where each cache line of `a` was manually evicted; both these tricks enabled by KNC obviously worked as we wanted to for `b` over 16 kiB. The code of the measured loop is as follows:

```
while (a_ptr < a_ptr_end) {
#ifdef NTLOAD
   __m512i aa = _mm512_extload_epi64((__m512i*)a_ptr,
      _MM_UPCONV_EPI64_NONE, _MM_BROADCAST64_NONE, _MM_HINT_NT);
#else
   __m512i aa = _mm512_load_epi64((__m512i*)a_ptr);
#endif
   __m512i bb = _mm512_load_epi64((__m512i*)b_ptr);
   bb = _mm512_or_epi64(aa, bb);
   _mm512_store_epi64((__m512i*)b_ptr, bb);

#ifdef EVICT
   _mm_clevict(a_ptr, _MM_HINT_T0);
#endif

   a_ptr += 8;
   b_ptr += 8;
   if (b_ptr >= b_ptr_end)
       b_ptr = b;
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

On Xeon Phi, `icpc` generated for normal-load variant (orange curve) prefetching for `a_ptr`:

```
400e93:       62 d1 78 08 18 4c 24    vprefetch0 [r12+0x80]
```

When I manually (by hex-editing the executable) modified this to:

```
400e93:       62 d1 78 08 18 44 24    vprefetchnta [r12+0x80]
```

I got the desired resutls, even better than the blue/gray curves. However, I was not able to force the compiler to generate non-temporal prefetchnig for me, even by using `#pragma prefetch a_ptr:_MM_HINT_NTA` before the loop :(

Comment: Great stuff. Can you post or share (eg on GitHub) the full code, inclduing the variant with prefetching?

Comment: ... as far as I know, the NTA prefetch hints forced the lines into a single way of the cache, which avoids most pollution - but I don't think it was necessarily the L1 cache, but perhaps the L2 or L3. So perhaps your test would show results if you tested at the sizes that impact those caches.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: See https://github.com/DanielLangr/ntload

Comment: Awesome. It might be worthwhile phrasing your question as a question. As it stands, it's just research, but what is the question you want to know? If I understood it correctly, you want to know something like: "Do current x86 architectures support non-temporal loads?". I think you can omit the prefetching part, because it's really included in "load" - on method to _load_ data is indeed to ensure it is prefetched.

Comment: Since I don't see this link anywhere: the idea for this microbenchmark came from: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-isa-extensions/topic/597075

Comment: I used your test program to look for MOVNTDQA avoiding pollution of L2 or L3 on Skylake.  (Like you, I didn't find any L1 diff).  I *think* there's a small benefit to NT loads for sizes between 4MB and 8MB (i.e. over half L3 size on my i7-6700k), much smaller than what you found for KNC.  I couldn't find any difference between test and test-nt in the 128 to 300kiB range (L2->L3 transition).  So there seems to be no effect on L1 or L2, but maybe on L3.  Will try to confirm with more tightly-controlled tests, and perf counters.

Comment: It's hard because SKL decides to downclock itself when only running memory-bound code, but that has an effect on memory bandwidth.

Comment: In regarding to your UPDATE 2, if you append _mm_prefetch(a_ptr, _MM_HINT_NTA); just after the while, the compiler generate vprefetchnta; I am using g++ (Debian 6.3.0-18) 6.3.0 20170516. I can not launch the test, because I don't have the necessary hardware.

Comment: As @BeeOnRope  stated _It might be worthwhile phrasing your question as a question._. Specifically, move most of the content of the question into your own answer. See https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ for why you would want to do this.

Comment: How would I run this and gather the necessary data on my machine? Could you write up some instructions?

Comment: @Blacksilver The code is on GitHub and the link is provided in my comment above. Target platforms are Intel Haswell and Intel Xeon Phi KNC (native mode). For Haswell code, you will need PAPI.

Comment: (Update re: my earlier comment about SKL downclocking the CPU core(s) on memory-bound workloads: [Slowing down CPU Frequency by imposing memory stress](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63399456).  One way to defeat this is with energy_performance_preference = performance.  Or I guess telling the OS to manage P-states itself for the duration of your benchmarking session, instead of handing off to hardware P-state management.)

Answer (score 10):

To answer specifically the headline question:

*Yes*, recent<sup>1</sup> mainstream Intel CPUs support non-temporal loads on *normal <sup>2</sup>* memory - but only "indirectly" via non-temporal prefetch instructions, rather than directly using non-temporal load instructions like `movntdqa`. This is in contrast to non-temporal stores where you can just use the corresponding non-temporal store instructions<sup>3</sup> directly.

The basic idea is that you issue a `prefetchnta` to the cache line before any normal loads, and then issue loads as normal. If the line wasn't already in the cache, it will be loaded in a non-temporal fashion. The exact meaning of *non-temporal fashion* depends on the architecture but the general pattern is that the line is loaded into, at least the L1 and perhaps some higher cache levels. Indeed for a prefetch to be of any use it needs to cause the line to load, at least into *some* cache level for consumption by a later load. The line may also be treated specially in the cache, for example by flagging it as high priority for eviction or restricting the ways in which it can be placed.

The upshot of all this is that while non-temporal loads are *supported* in a sense, they are really only partly non-temporal, unlike stores where you really leave no trace of the line in any of the cache levels. Non-temporal loads will cause *some* cache pollution, but generally less than regular loads. The exact details are architecture specific, and I've included some details below for modern Intel. You can find a slightly longer writeup [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47959255/149138) to the question "Non-temporal loads and the hardware prefetcher, do they work together?"
).

#### Skylake Client

Based on the tests [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47959255/149138) it seems that the behavior for `prefetchnta` Skylake is to fetch normally into the L1 cache, to skip the L2 entirely, and fetches in a limited way into the L3 cache (probably into 1 or 2 ways only so the total amount of the L3 available to `nta` prefetches is limited).

This was tested on [Skylake client](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/microarchitectures/skylake_(client)), but I believe this basic behavior probably extends backwards probably to Sandy Bridge and earlier (based on wording in the Intel optimization guide), and also forwards to Kaby Lake and later architectures based on Skylake client. So unless you are using a Skylake-SP or Skylake-X part, or an extremely old CPU, this is probably the behavior you can expect from `prefetchnta`.

#### Skylake Server

The only recent Intel chip known to have different behavior is [Skylake server](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/microarchitectures/skylake_(server)) (used in Skylake-X, Skylake-SP and a few other lines). This has a considerably changed L2 and L3 architecture, and the L3 is no longer inclusive of the much larger L2. For this chip, it seems that `prefetchnta` skips *both* the L2 and L3 caches, so on this architecture cache pollution is limited to the L1.

This behavior was [reported by user Mysticial in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48994494/how-to-properly-use-prefetch-instructions/48995540?noredirect=1#comment84996972_48994494). The downside, as pointed out in those comments is that this makes `prefetchnta` much more brittle: if you get the prefetch distance or timing wrong (especially easy when hyperthreading is involved and the sibling core is active), and the data gets evicted from L1 before you use, you are going all the way back to main memory rather than the L3 on earlier architectures.

---

<sup>1</sup> *Recent* here probably means anything in the last decade or so, but I don't mean to imply that earlier hardware didn't support non-temporal prefetch: it's possible that support goes right back to the introduction of `prefetchnta` but I don't have the hardware to check that and can't find an existing reliable source of information on it.

<sup>2</sup> *Normal* here just means WB (writeback) memory, which is the memory dealing with at the application level the overwhelming majority of the time.

<sup>3</sup> Specifically, the NT store instructions are `movnti` for general purpose registers and the `movntd*` and `movntp*` families for SIMD registers.

Answer (score 5):

I answer my own question since I found the following post from Intel Developer Forum, which makes sense for me. It was written by John McCalpin:

> The results for the mainstream processors are not surprising -- in the absence of true "scratchpad" memory, it is not clear that it is possible to design an implementation of "non-temporal" behavior that is not subject to nasty surprises.   **Two approaches that have been used in the past are (1) loading the cache line, but marking it LRU instead of MRU, and (2) loading the cache line into one specific "set" of the set-associative cache.  In either case it is relatively easy to generate situations in which the cache drops the data before the processor completes reading it.**
>
> Both of these approaches risk performance degradation in cases operating on more than a small number of arrays, and are made much more difficult to implement without "gotchas" when HyperThreading is considered.
>
> In other contexts I have argued for the implementation of "load multiple" instructions that would guarantee that the entire contents of a cache line would be copied to registers atomically.  My reasoning is that the hardware absolutely guarantees that the cache line is moved atomically and that the time required to copy the remainder of the cache line to registers was so small  (an extra 1-3 cycles, depending on the processor generation) that it could be safely implemented as an atomic operation.
>
> Starting with Haswell, the core can read 64 Bytes in a single cycle (2 256-bit aligned AVX reads), so the exposure to unintended side effects becomes even lower.
>
> Starting with KNL, full-cache-line (aligned) loads should be "naturally" atomic, since the transfers from the L1 Data Cache to the core are full cache lines and all of the data is placed into the target AVX-512 register.  (This does not mean that Intel guarantees atomicity in the implementation!  We don't have visibility into the horrible corner cases that the designers have to account for, but it is reasonable to conclude that *most of the time* aligned 512-bit loads will occur atomically.)    With this "natural" 64-Byte atomicity, some of the tricks used in the past for reducing cache pollution due to "non-temporal" loads may deserve another look....

---

> **The MOVNTDQA instruction is intended primarily for reading from address ranges that are mapped as "Write-Combining" (WC), and not for reading from normal system memory that is mapped "Write-Back" (WB).    The description in Volume 2 of the SWDM says that an implementation "may" do something special with MOVNTDQA for WB regions, but the emphasis is on the behavior for the WC memory type.**
>
> The "Write-Combining" memory type is almost never used for "real" memory --- it is used almost exclusively for Memory-Mapped IO regions.

See here for the whole post: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-isa-extensions/topic/597075

Comment: I think one of the major reasons for ignoring the NT hint on `movntdqa` loads from WB memory is that hardware or software prefetch is critical for performance, but without support from a HW prefetcher that knows about NT loads and tracks those streams separately from regular streams, it makes more sense to just not do anything special.  So use `prefetchnta` + `movdqa`.  (Or don't use `prefetchnta`; it tends to be "brittle".  If you get the prefetch distance wrong, you're loading from L3, not L2.  Or on SKX where L3 isn't inclusive, from main memory if L1d is evicted before you get to it.)